# redis server does not start

Tags: nosql, redis

Hi I have the following problem with redis,

- I have installed redis on Ubuntu 12.10 with

  sudo apt-get install redis-server

However, then comes the start of the message server

[6793] February 6 21:46:54 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use 'redis-server / path / to / redis.conf'
[6793] 6 February 6379 21:46:54 # Opening port: bind: Address already in use

What can I do that the server starts?

Answer (score 3):

You should stop the current instance by using the following command.

```
/etc/init.d/redis-server stop
```

Answer (score 1):

The default port for Redis, 6793, is already being used, so you'll need to find out what is using that port.

You can check by running: `lsof -i :6793`

You'll then need to either kill whatever is using that port or specify a different port for Redis using a config file.

Comment: Depends what's using the port. Don't just kill whatever is using it… You can create a config file anywhere and use it as stated in the error message you pasted in your question. It's probably worth checking the Redis documentation, you might find it was created for explaining these sort of questions.

Comment: if I lsof-i: 6793 applying is nothing, no response, no error message!

Comment: That's not the default port -- `6379` is. Try `lsof -i :6379`. The config file for Ubuntu's redis-server package is `/etc/redis/redis.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

pidof redis-server can get you the process id of redis-server;
OR lsof -i:6379 can get you the process id of the running instance with the default listening port 6379.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check the log file for the troubleshooting possible errors.
Usually located at /var/log/redis/redis.log